# Should I use DotNetNuke Controls instead of standard ASP controls and where I can find documentation for them?

Tags: user-interface, documentation, controls, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I'm starting with DNN 5.5 development and I noticed that there exists DNN versions of standard asp web controls.
As you have standard asp control like `Button` or `DataGrid`, you also have special DNN version of this controls `DnnButton`, `DnnDataGrid`,...

- So what is the benefit if I use DNN
  version of controls, if I understand
  correctly this simplifies theming of
  your DNN web page and brings you more
  uniform look.
- Where can I find any documentation
  about this DNN versions of controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is non-existent, so far as I can tell (outside of the code itself).

Some of the controls are just simple wrappers which do localization for you (i.e. just set the `Text` property, don't use `ResourceKey`).

Some of the controls use the corresponding Telerik control, apply a skin to the control (Simple skin plus potential control-specific CSS from the DNN skin), and also do the localization<sup>(1)</sup>.  If you don't have a Telerik license, these wrappers are your only access to the bundled Telerik controls.

Some of the controls are more prescriptive combinations of controls.

It is my assumption that DNN is going to start using these controls exclusively, so it will help the uniformity of your site to use them.  However, it's not a *huge* advantage (or officially announced), so where it's easier to ignore them, don't get too worried.

<sup>(1)</sup>One thing to note is that there are some issues with bad localization in the DnnGrid which is fixed in DNN 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a style guide that describes all of the controls available, it was mentioned at DevConnections (by Shaun). It also touches on the some best practices too.

I know it is floating around internally @ DNN Corp and to some on the UX teas but I am not sure when it will be publicly made available.